# Export whole database on server and return url to download

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

Is there any tool which could dump export whole db (structure +data), save the bd_sql.zip on server & return url for download the dp dump?

I found [LazyDbBackup](http://www.joomxtensions.com/en/how-to-use-lazydbbackup.html) but it is cron type plugin and I need to allow admin to just a button for db dump when he require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good I got it [DataSafe](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/20003) !

It the plugin which I was searching.. :)